# Set Notation Excercise

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am working through some set theory exercises, and am stuck with this one:

$A = \left \{ 2,4,6,7,11 \right \}$

Find the set S1:

$S1 = \left \{ (n+4): n \in A) \right \}$

Taking away 4 from each member, of the set I get:

$A = \left \{ -2,0,2,3,7 \right \}$

The applet tells me the answer is wrong, but I can't figure out how!

Comment: What you wrote is the set $\{n:n+4\in A\}$. Do you see the difference with the original question?

Comment: Ahh. So, it infact should be: $A = \left \{ 6,8,10,11,15\right \}$

Comment: Yes, exactly : )

Comment: Note that the correct TeX for set membership is `\in` rather than `\epsilon`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't want to take away $4$ but you want to add $4$:

$$ S_1 = \{ n + 4 \mid n \in \{ 2,4,6,7,11\} \} = \{ 2 + 4, 4 + 4, 6 + 4, 7 + 4, 11 + 4\} = \{ 6, 8, 10, 11, 15\}$$